# putting this javascript and php into codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

```
<?php
// This is a code to check the username from a mysql database table

if(isSet($_POST['username']))
{
$username = $_POST['username'];

include("dbconnection.php");

$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT user FROM {$prefix}users WHERE user='$username'");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql_check))
{
echo '<span style="color: red;">The username <b>'.$username.'</b> is already in use.</span>';
}
else
{
echo 'OK';
}}
?>
```

that is the check.php witch i can change with no problem to work with CI its the below i need help with!

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">/script>
<script type="text/javascript">
pic1 = new Image(16, 16);
pic1.src = "loader.gif";

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#username").change(function() {

var usr = $("#username").val();

if(usr.length >= 3)
{
$("#status").html('<img align="absmiddle" src="loader.gif" /> Checking availability...');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "check.php",
data: "username="+ usr,
success: function(msg){

$("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){

if(msg == 'OK')
{
$("#username").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
$("#username").addClass("object_ok");
$(this).html(' <img align="absmiddle" src="accepted.png" /> ');
}
else
{
$("#username").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
$("#username").addClass("object_error");
$(this).html(msg);
}});}});}
else
{
$("#status").html('The username should have at least 3 characters.');
$("#username").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
$("#username").addClass("object_error");
}});});

//-->

</script>
```

i understand most of what this scrip is doing and i can make it work in a normal PHP but i am using code ignighter. if i am reading it right i should only have to change the line url: "check.php", and of course the original php can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: Is the check.php file sitting in the controller folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check at the following URL

- http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/184474/#872346

Comment: would you help me with the working link. The given link doesnt work @rod nelson